# Upload image yii 2 on server

Tags: image, upload, yii2

I am new with yii 2(basic) and i just upload all my files on server and i have a problem - i can't set image to my article, it dosn't works. Uploading works localy but on the server it dosn't works.
This is my .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1
```

This is my method with getting folder

```
private function getFolder()
{
    return Yii::getAlias('@web') . 'uploads/';
}
```

This is problem with htaccess or code or what ?)
Thx for feedback :)

Comment: Your uploads folder has write permission for the web server, right?

Comment: well i just added @app/web and it works, i don't know why :)